# Warning: return from incompatible pointer type in C

Tags: c, pointers, return

The below code generates an incompatible pointer type error and warning: control reaches end of non-void function in the filename function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int quit;
char *filename(int *);

int main ()
{   
    filename(&quit);   
    return 0;
}

char *filename(int *i1)
{
    char input[16];
    char *dum=(char*)malloc(16*sizeof(char));    
    if (dum==NULL){
        printf("Memory could not be allocated \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Memory was allocated – remember to free\n \n");    
        *i1=1;    
        fputs("Input filename = ", stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);    
        printf("Filename = \"%s\"\n",input);   
        return i1;

    }
}
```

I'm new to this, can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Your `main` function calls `filename` without using the return value, so why does the function need to return anything?

Comment: Actually, the question should be: why doesn't `main` use the return value? You print "remember to free", but then never free it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes? The function is declared to return `char *`, but you return `i1` which is the input argument and has type `int *`.

You might mean to return the newly allocated string `dum`, and perhaps also fill it with the data that was read using `fgets()` to the separate character array `input`. In this case, you need to copy the data over, and return `dum`.

It would be more concise, simpler, and generally better to read directly into `dum`:

```
fgets(dum, 16, stdin);

return dum;
```

Note that this duplicates the size of the buffer from the `malloc()` call, which is a "code smell". This can be improved by making it a local constant in the function:

```
char * filename(void)
{
  const size_t max_fn = 16;
  char *dum;

  if((dum = malloc(max_fn)) != NULL)
  {
    if(fgets(dum, max_fn, stdin) != dum)
    {
      free(dum);  /* Input failed, free the buffer and drop the pointer. */
      dum = NULL;
    }
  }
  return dum;
}
```

My latter code also has the benefit that it checks return values of functions that can fail. Both memory allocation (`malloc()`) and I/O (`fgets()`) can fail, so you must check their return values.

Comment: Thank you very much, like I said, I'm new to this and your comment has helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what unwind has said you should return something after the line `printf("Memory could not be allocated \n");`

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly, your indenting is appalling. Reindenting this makes it a little clearer what is going on:

```
char *filename(int *i1)
{
    char input[16];
    char *dum=(char*)malloc(16*sizeof(char));

    if (dum==NULL){
        printf("Memory could not be allocated \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Memory was allocated – remember to free\n \n");

        *i1=1;

        fputs("Input filename = ", stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);

        printf("Filename = \"%s\"\n",input);

        return i1;

    }
}
```

So in one path of the if, you return 'i1' which is an int pointer, which is most definitely not a char pointer.

In the other half, you just drop through to the end of the function, which returns nothing.

You are lucky your compiler warns you about this. A lot, by default, just ignore that.

as an aside, you have a memory leak. You malloc memory for dum, but never free it.